# Passing a pointer to a char array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, function-pointers

I have a pointer to my char array like this.

```
    unsigned char *recvBuf;
    recvBuf = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*RECVBUF);
```

I then pass that to a function defined as

```
void setHeader(MyHeader *myHeader, unsigned char *buffer)
```

Which copies the first 12 bytes into a struct

Then I try and pass it to another function later on

```
Record readRecord(unsigned char *buffer, int *arrayPosition, int buffsize)
```

But the program always becomes unresponsive when I try and access any part of the array using [], in the exact same way it was used in the previous functiom. And i'm also fine to access it like that before i pass it to the function.

Ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

Pointers are the same.

This is inside the second function

I added this code to the top and it works just fine

```
int k = *arrayPosition;
    printf("%p \n", buffer);

    printf("%c \n", buffer[k]);
```

This is the original code, the program becomes unresponsive adfter i = *arrayposition...

```
int i, j;
Record *myRecord;
Resource *myResource;
unsigned char name[255];
unsigned char data[50];
unsigned int offset;

i = *arrayPosition;

while(buffer[i] != '\0')
{
    if((buffer[i] & 0xC000) == 0xC000)
    {
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't modify the value of the pointer inside one of the function? Do you dereference the pointer when inserting data?

Comment: Some stylistic concerns: In C (but not C++) it's generally considered bad style to cast the return value of `malloc`, as `void *` is implicitly converted to any other pointer type. Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 in C (and C++), so multiplying by it is redundant. The second line of code should just be this: `recvBuf = malloc(RECVBUF);`.

Comment: I think that most compilers will remove that redundancy. Sometimes it's used just to write clearer code: size_of_item * number_of_items

Comment: It's interesting that you're using the term "unresponsive", if you were dereferencing a bad pointer I would expect a crash / core.  Is it possible you're spinning in that while( buffer[i] != '\0' ) loop?  Perhaps you're not incrementing i via some control path?

Answer (score 2):

Really need more context to assist here, there's nothing obviously untoward from what you've said.

Basics:

1. Check that you haven't indexed off
   the end of your memory block.
2. Check that you're not passing
   &recvBuf where you mean to pass
   recvBuf?  A compiler should
   catch this, but you'd trash your stack if you did this, maybe using a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Input is not enough to be sure of the problem that makes the pointer go bad but a good catch would be to check with gdb if the pointer changes between the function call you descripted.

Do you modify any char of the array? You should dereference the pointer with `*` in that case.

If you cannot use the pointer after the call causes can be:

1. it is changed erroneously inside the function
2. it is a pointer to an allocated value in the stack that is deallocated implicitly somewhere (but it sounds strange)